# return character in fuction

Tags: c, pointers

I have some basic question about the pointers, I have a char array and I am extracting some words my char array with using function  and I want to return value and print it main I have Code But it's not working, thanks for your help

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    char cumle[30];
char kelimecikart(char *cumle,char *sozcuk);
int main(){
    int i;
    char sozcuk[30];
    printf("sentence:\n");
    gets(cumle);
    puts(cumle);

    printf("What is the word you want to extract of:\n");
    gets(sozcuk);
    puts(sozcuk);
    printf("\n");

    cumle[0]=kelimecikart(cumle,sozcuk);
    for(i=0;i<17;i++){

        printf("%c",cumle[i]);
    }
}
char kelimecikart(char *dizi,char *cikansoz)
{    
    int a = strlen(dizi);
    int b = strlen(cikansoz);

    int i,j,tmp=0;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            if(*(dizi+i+j)==*(cikansoz+j)){
                tmp++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
            }
            if(tmp==b){
                i+=tmp-1;
            }
            else{
                *(cumle+i)=*(dizi+i);
            }
            tmp=0;  
    }   

    return *cumle;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    char cumle[30];
void kelimecikart(char *cumle,char *sozcuk);
int main(){
    int i;
    char sozcuk[30];
    printf("sentence:\n");
    gets(cumle);
    puts(cumle);

    printf("What is the word you want to extract of:\n");
    gets(sozcuk);
    puts(sozcuk);
    printf("\n");

    kelimecikart(cumle,sozcuk);
    for(i=0;i<17;i++){

        printf("%c",cumle[i]);
    }
}
void kelimecikart(char *dizi,char *cikansoz)
{    
    int a = strlen(dizi);
    int b = strlen(cikansoz);
    int i,j=1;
    for(i=0;i<a;){
        if(j==0){
            i++;
        }
        else if(j==b){
            break;
        } 
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            if(dizi[i]==cikansoz[j]){
                i++;

            }
            else{
                break;
            }

        }
    }



    for(;i<a;i++){
        dizi[i-b]=dizi[i];

    }

    return ;
}
//
```